# Ratio of totient $\varphi(n)/\varphi(n+1)$

Tags: number-theory

Is there a general formula for the ratio of totients of two consecutive integers? It occurred to me in a different context, where I was trying to find a different way of estimating the probability of drawing a random rational number in the interval $(0,1)$. One could represent a rational number as an ordered pair of co-primes $(m,n)$ with $m<n$. Suppose we put a uniform, finitely additive measure on the set $\{(m,n)\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}: m, n \text{co-prime}, m<n\}$. Then fixing $n$, there are only $\varphi(n)$ many rational numbers with denominator $n$, which is what brought me to the question of $\varphi(n)/\varphi(n+1)$. Ideally it would be great if the formula could be a function of $n$ alone (sorry this might still be vague). Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You'll get a better response if you include context in your question. For example, how did this question occur to you? What have you tried? Also, most importantly, what sort of formula are you looking for? After all, $\varphi(n)/\varphi(n+1)$ is a formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have edited the question to include my motivations.

Comment: I think the addition of motivation has significantly improved the question, and I've upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\;n=p_1^{a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_m^{a_m}\;,\;\;p_i,\,a_i\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;p_i$ primes, then we know that

$$\phi(n)=n\prod_{k=1}^m\left(1-\frac1{p_k}\right)$$

so you can then write

$$\frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(n+1)}=\frac n{n+1}\prod_{p\mid n,\,q\mid (n+1)}\left(1-\frac1p\right)\left(1-\frac1q\right)^{-1}$$

It doesn't really look very nice a formula, though...

Comment: Thanks! Yes ideally I would like a formula that does not invoke facts about prime factorization of $n$, but that might be impossible...

Comment: @discretizer I can nearly guarantee you it is impossible. There are a lot of open problems similar to this one.

Comment: **Happy New Year**, my friend !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Bonne Anneé, mon ami !